# Filter a webpage html with the 'WebBrowser' in visual studio C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I am making a simple web browser in Visual Studio c# which when opened goes to my website, I want to be able to somehow cut out bits of the html that gets rendered on the webpage. So far my WebBrowser works perfectly fine, i just need to be able to somehow listen to the incoming html code of the page, i will then remove the bits i don't need. Is it possible to do this with the WebBrowser in Visual Studio c#? If so could someone explain how it could be achieved.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A first approach would be getting the HTML with a web request:

```
HttpWebRequest myReq =
(HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://whatever.com/");
WebResponse response = myReq.GetResponse();
Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd(); //Here's the complete HTML content
reader.Close ();
response.Close ();
```

After that you parse the HTML for your needs (delete something you don't need etc.)

For HTML parsing see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56107/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-html-in-c).

In the end you simply pass that parsed HTML to your WebBrowser, for example like this:

```
myWebBrowser.DocumentText =
    "<html><body>" + myParsedContent +
    "</body></html>";
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll take a look and see how it goes :)

Comment: You are welcome :-). If you have any questions feel free to ask them